# Power BI Dax Measure moving Sum by categories

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax, measure

im struggling with the following problem. I have categorical variables and and Amount column. What I want to do is, to write a dax measure which calculates the moving/rolling Sum, like you see in the third column "Dax Measure". Did not find any inhouse Dax function for that.

[moving sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMkFu.png)

EDIT:

[Result Table with Dax Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEkEQ.png)

[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urdTg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the category is always sorted ASC.

```
Dax measure = 
VAR _currentRank = RANKX(ALL('Table'[Category]),CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Category])),,ASC)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Amount]),TOPN(_currentRank,VALUES('Table'[Category]),MIN([Category]))),
    ALL('Table'[Category])
)
```

Using RANKX to define the other and aggregating for all the item before it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually does not work. I reproduced within power bi. The Dax measure does not give the right cummulative values.

Comment: This works. Would you please share more information regarding your model and the query you wrote to see why it does not work on your specific case.

Comment: I edited my post with the source table and the result table.

Comment: @bonus copy the formula again. Should work now

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Did you copy the new version? ignore the image, was still the old one. If it is not working .. good luck

Comment: Yes, I have copied the new version, unfortuanely the calculation is wrong.